# Enabling Locks on Azure Private Endpoint - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to enable Azure Lock on private endpoint resources if only defined in the variable file. But when we apply it always trying to process the resource block even, we don't defined the variable. refer to the following code blocks.

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_endpoints" {
  for_each = {for key,value in local.private_endpoints : key => value if coalesce(var.private_endpoints.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
  name       = coalesce(azurerm_private_endpoint.this[each.value].name, "lock-${azurerm_private_endpoint.this[each.value].name}")
  scope = azurerm_private_endpoint.this[each.value].id
  lock_level = var.lock.kind
}
```

**variable.tf**

````
variable "private_endpoints" {
  type = object({
    resource_group_name = optional(string)
    subnet_id           = string
    tags                = optional(map(string))
    lock_level              = optional(string)
    private_service_connection = object({
      name_prefix = string
    })
    timeouts = optional(object({
      create = optional(string)
      delete = optional(string)
      read   = optional(string)
      update = optional(string)
    }))
  })
}


variable "lock" {
  type = object({
    name = optional(string, null)
    kind = optional(string, "None")
  })
  description = <<LOCK
    "The lock level to apply to this Storage Account and all of it's child resources. The default value is none. Possible values are `None`, `CanNotDelete`, and `ReadOnly`. Set the lock value on child resource values explicitly to override any inherited locks."

    Example Inputs:
    ```terraform
    lock = {
      name = "lock-{resourcename}" # optional
      type = "CanNotDelete"
    }
    ```
    LOCK
  default     = {}
  nullable    = false
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["CanNotDelete", "ReadOnly", "None"], var.lock.kind)
    error_message = "The lock level must be one of: 'None', 'CanNotDelete', or 'ReadOnly'."
  }
}
````

**Error**

```
│ Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 630, in resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_endpoints":
│  630:   for_each = {for key,value in local.private_endpoints : key => value if coalesce(var.private_endpoints.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private_endpoints is null
│
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried Enabling Locks on Azure Private Endpoint using Terraform and i was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The blocker you got indicates that var.private_endpoints is null, which means the private_endpoints variable is either not defined in your Terraform variables file or is passed as null. When you try to access attributes of a null object in Terraform, it results in an error.

To overcome this issue make a note of the things I mentioned.

- Make sure that the `private_endpoints` variable has a default value if it's optional, to avoid null value issues.
- Add a check to handle the scenario where `var.private_endpoints` might be null.

To enable lock on the resource I tried using the configuration mentioned by taking a demo example using **storage account** and **subnet** by creating a **private endpoint** with a **lock** for it.

**My Terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoints["example"].subnet_id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "demovk-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = var.private_endpoints["example"].private_service_connection.resource_id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["blob"] 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this_private_endpoints" {
  for_each = var.private_endpoints != null ? { for key, value in var.private_endpoints : key => value if coalesce(value.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None" } : {}

  name       = "lock-${each.key}"
  scope      = azurerm_private_endpoint.example.id
  lock_level = var.lock.kind
}
```

##### variable.tf

```
variable "private_endpoints" {
  description = "A map of private endpoints configurations"
  type = map(object({
    resource_group_name        = optional(string)
    subnet_id                  = string
    tags                       = optional(map(string))
    lock_level                 = optional(string)
    private_service_connection = object({
      name_prefix = string
      resource_id = string
    })
    timeouts = optional(object({
      create = optional(string)
      delete = optional(string)
      read   = optional(string)
      update = optional(string)
    }))
  }))
  default = {}
}

variable "lock" {
  type = object({
    name = optional(string, null)
    kind = optional(string, "None")
  })
  description = "Lock configuration for the resources"
  default     = {
    name = null
    kind = "None"
  }
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["CanNotDelete", "ReadOnly", "None"], var.lock.kind)
    error_message = "The lock level must be one of: 'None', 'CanNotDelete', or 'ReadOnly'."
  }
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
private_endpoints = {
  "example" = {
    subnet_id = "/subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/your_vnet/subnets/your_subnet"
    private_service_connection = {
      name_prefix = "example"
      resource_id = "/subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group/providersMicrosoft.Storage/storageAccounts/your_storage_Account"
    }
  }
}

lock = {
  kind = "CanNotDelete"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]